# Swift get json data and index out of range error

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

My question is simple but I couldn't find a solution. When I get JSON data from server I want to display the data to collectionviewcell but I got index out of range error.

This is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SiparislerTumAnasayfa", for: indexPath) as! SiparislerTumAnasayfa
    let url = URL(string: "https://abc/api/SiparislerTumListeler/abc")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {
            if data != nil{
                do{
                    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                        self.jsonArray = responseJSON["results"] as? [[String: Any]]

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            let row = self.jsonArray![indexPath.row]
                            if let urunAdi = row["siparis_urun_adi"] as? String {
                                cell.siparisUrunAdi.text = urunAdi
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.jsonArray!.count
}
```

`[indexPath.row]` is where I got the error.

Comment: Why are you doing the API call inside `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`?

Comment: i tried in viweDidload() but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code that handles the case where `indexPath.row` is greater or equal to `self.jsonArray.count`.

Comment: you mean "numberOfItemsInSection" rigth ?

Comment: That's also an important method (which you don't show), but yes, apparently it tells the collection view that there are more cells than you whatever you have in your JSON `data`.

Comment: Ouch. That's really bad, asynchronously getting and parsing the same JSON over and over again in each `cellForItem` call. Move that code e.g. to your `viewDidLoad()` so it only runs once. Also, look into `Codable` so you can avoid `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: i did and now i got Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the number of array from response api are less than the numberOfItemsInSection
`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {....}`